# Slide in from the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is basically my current website:

https://jsfiddle.net/s0wgnvk2/

And now I have the problem in the #About section when I click right it goes to #right section and, you can't see it in fiddle but in my webpage the transition is really smooth and I like it how it is, but I just don't know how to make it work for the left side since it is positioned left:-100%.

```
$(function() {
    $('#About a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, 1000);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I know about the fullPage.js plugin but I'd like to have my own solution and web layout even thought fullPage is probably a lot better.

I would appreciate if you could help me out

**EDIT**

Fiddle corrected: https://jsfiddle.net/s0wgnvk2/1/

Comment: there is no Jquery attached to the fiddle. here is the correct one. https://jsfiddle.net/s0wgnvk2/1/

Comment: yeah, thanks for noticing that, somehow i always forget to include it :)
Any ideas how to make the left side work?

Comment: i can say there isn't something wrong with your code, it seems like scrollLeft having trouble handling negative values. have you checked the documentation?

Comment: yeah scrollLeft converts negative values to 0. that's why your animation seem to be not working

Comment: argh i've just found that out aswell, what am I to do then so it stays fluent on both sides. I'm a complete noob so any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scrollLeft denotes the scroll bar position from the left, see ref [here](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/). So it cannot be negative (the left most position is 0).

What you need might be `marginLeft`, try:

```
$('html, body').animate({ marginLeft: '100%' });
```

Here is a working jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/xbsdn0u8/2/). Note that I have make the header position: fix, so that it knows where to anchor and how to width itself when the left margin of the  element  changes.

Comment: and how would i implement in in that piece of code. I just found that animate solution on the internet and as I said i'm a complete noob in JS/jQuery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s0wgnvk2/7/

when i put this line of code like this in jsfiddle it works great but my navigation bar and header just disappear

Comment: @JesusChrist this is because your header is positioned statically. You need to position it absolutely so that when the margin of <html> and <body> changes, it knows where to anchor. Position fixed is also okay, see my example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xbsdn0u8/2/). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use **animation** not scroll
see what issue you face when you use scroll https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/s0wgnvk2/4/

> And as you said in your site animation is working smoothly and not in fiddle
>   that is because you **haven't selected jauery** from droupdown which is
>   present in left side of fiddle editor so your animation is not working so if you see your console it will give you **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined** in your example https://jsfiddle.net/s0wgnvk2/

Left right animation Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/vunL9ec2/

```
 $('#About a').bind('click', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        if ($anchor.context.innerHTML === "RIGHT" ) {
            $($anchor.attr('href')).stop().animate({
                left: '-=100%'
            }, 1000);
        } else if ($anchor.context.innerHTML === "LEFT") {
            $($anchor.attr('href')).stop().animate({
                left: '+=100%'
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            console.log($(this).context.offsetParent.id )
            $('#'+$(this).context.offsetParent.id ).stop().animate({
                left: $(this).context.offsetParent.id ==='right'?'+=100%':'-=100%'
            }, 1000);


        }
```

Comment: This solution is good thank you but it's not the exact thing i had in mind and if you press few times in a row left and right anchor it gets messed up

Comment: so can you tell me what you want i will  help you @JesusChrist

Comment: Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/s0wgnvk2/8/

It works just as i want it to but my navigation bar and header just disappear. If you can help me with that I would be grateful

Comment: @JesusChrist see i update your fiddle for only header part see and let me know it is correct or not  https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/s0wgnvk2/9/

Comment: and you are using marginleft after animation then there is one issue i.e when you click on left then middle will be automatically close in your fiddle